# Why does it says that couldn't open shooting_game\player.png on Pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Why does it says that couldn't open shooting_game\player.png on Pygame?
Here's my code so far:

```
import pygame
import os

width, height = 500, 400

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Shooter Game")

player = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("shooter_game", "player.png"))
```

This gives me a error:

```
Exception has occurred: error
Couldn't open shooter_game/player.png
  File "C:\python_games\shooter_game\game.py", line 11, in <module>
    player = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("shooter_game", "player.png"))
```

I maked sure that `player.png`'s folder was
in the same folder as `game.py`'s folder.

Can someone help me figure out this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If `player.png` is in the same folder as `game.py`, you should look for it in the `shooter_game` directory:

```py
player = pygame.image.load("player.png")
```

Comment: I did look in the `shooter_game` folder but still don't work.

Answer (score 0):

Relative paths are based on current working directory, not the script's directory. If you happen to have changed to the script's directory to run it, they are both the same and it works by shear luck. Otherwise you'll get this error. Python scripts have a `__file__` variable holding the script's file name. You can leverage that to find the directory.

```
player = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))), 
    "player.png")
```

`pathlib` has an alternate way of handling file system paths

```
from pathlib import Path
player = pygame.image.load(Path(__file__).absolute().parent/"player.png")
```